# Tracking users geolocation in web application

Tags: reactjs, web, geolocation

I am writing an React-application that needs to track users geolocation in background, so that even if I closw browser, it keeps tracking it.

Is there a way to do this in web? When searching in google, I get answers only for Android/React Native

Comment: That'd be scary if you could.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: no. Once the website is closed, there is no more script running. So you cannot keep tracking the device.